# How to debug wince exe directly without using a vcproj

Tags: debugging, windows-ce

I'd like to humbly ask: How can I debug a wince executable(.exe) that has been stored on the wince device, using Visual Studio's debugging facility.

As we all know, using VS2005, we can create a Win32 Smart Device Project(.vcproj)，add our source files to it, compile, select a target device, and press F5, then the generated exe will be deployed to the wince device and gets attached to the VS2005 wince debugger. But I'd really like to know, if someone has a wince exe(call it stock) already in his wince-device and have source code corresponding to that exe, HOW DO I start debugging that stock exe directly WITHOUT compiling the source code? I cannot compile the source code perhaps because I'm missing some library source or other reason.

For PC program, I know I can open an exe as a project so to start debugging that exe. I can find the main() function and set a break point on its first statement, then F5 will stop at that break point.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often run into this problem as well; I wish the "exe project" created would allow changing the debugger to "Smart Device Native Debugger" (or somehow set the platform) -> Let me know if someone knows how to do that.

The two ways I have been able to work around this are:

1. New Project Method:

   - Create an empty "Smart Device" project with no source code.
   - Change the "Configuration Properties > Debugging > Remote Executable" to your "Stock EXE"  that you put on the device, ie: \FlashDisk\MyApp.exe
   - F5 to debug, and choose "Yes" when it says "deployment errors, do you wish to continue".
2. Attach to Process Method:

   - Same as above, but, instead of editing "Remote Executable" just start the "Stock EXE" via rapistart.exe / running manually via screen. Then make sure the "Attach to Process" transport is set to "Smart Device" and you should be able to attach.

After this you need to manually load the pdb, choose src files, etc, as you would a normal PC app.

Comment: (1/3) I know this is a very old "answer", but it is too brief to actually say what each step is.  For starters it fails to state which tool and version it uses against which CE edition and version.  Similarly, it mentions "rapistart" and "screen" without specifying what those words were intended to mean.  Was rapistart a program that is preinstalled on CE, something to be installed a specific way or a PC side tool that comes in some (unnamed) PC side installation package.

Comment: (2/3) Similarly is "screen" the physical touchscreen on the CE device, the desktop screen on the debugger PC or perhaps a Windows CE port of the famous UNIX/Linux program "screen".

Comment: (3/3)  One of the other answers below purports to expend on this answer, but clarifies none of these words from @user2093823's "head canon", showing only screenshots from an unnamed tool.

Comment: (1/2) I have now experimented and found the correct steps for method one.  First start Visual Studio 2005, then create a new project, category "Smart Device", subcategory "MFC application".  Doesn't matter what the hypothetical application class names are in the project definition screens, as you won't be actually adding those class names.
  Next in the drop down next to the Debug/Relase drop down, select the SDK for the test device.
  Next in the ActiveSync (XP) or Windows Mobile Device Center (Vista and later), "connect without setting up your device" ...

Comment: (2/2) Next back in the dummy VS2005 project, next to the drop down that says "Windows CE Device", press the "Device Options" button and in the dialog change "Show devices for platform" to the SDK for the test device, then the device category for the device.
 Finally, on the Main menu, open Debug!Attach to Process and in the dialog change Transport to "Smart Device", then next to qualifier, press "Browse" and select the device type from the SDK again and press "Connect".  Now the list of processes will be populated and the target process can be selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug a .NET CF managed application then the following link should help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1ksfbk7%28VS.80%29.aspx

I only used managed .NET CF but I found this link that has loads of goodies on how to debug both managed and native code on a Windows Mobile 5 in VS2005. Most of it should apply to Win CE as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446524.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the method lately after going through quite a lot of reading and experiment(so many tricky points that Microsoft does not clearly document). user2093823 kindly summarized the procedure.

Some historical screen shots:

[image]
[image]